# ગુજરાતી language in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a "Gujarati To English Dictionary" application using C#.

In which I would want that if user types "tajmhal" from the keyboard "તાજમહાલ" would be displayed in the TEXTBOX at the same time.

ie. If "koml" , "કોમલ" is displayed. etc...

I have downloaded and set the font for the textbox to "Gujarati Saral-1" and it works.

But when I store the text of the textbox to the database it is stored as "tajmhal" not "તાજમહાલ".

so, could you please suggest to me another solution?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you go into more detail about how it's meant to work?

Comment: Also please consider that everyone here doesn't understand native Indian languages..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: We love to see those sigils being (presumably) properly rendered by our browsers here, though ;-) Looks cool.

Comment: It sounds like you are only changing the display of the words by changing the font, this is not translating the data.

Comment: ya only font display is done here not actual translation.

Comment: my applixcation is simple having one textbox.when i type "koml" from the keyboard ,textbox should have text like "કોમલ".To whom not getting clear about my first post.please help me soon.

Comment: Hello @aarti did you get your this question solution. If yes, then please share your solution because I also stuck the same question.

Answer (score 7):

From what I call tell after looking at this [font info page](http://www.fonts2u.com/gujrati-saral-1.font) this font is NOT a Unicode font, but rather displays Latin code-points as Gujarati glyphs.

In order to make your idea work, you need to use a Gujarati Unicode-compliant font, and replace each Latin character with its equivalent character. See [this table](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0A80.pdf) for the Gujarati code-points.

Answer (score 6):

If the user types `tajmhal` from the keyboard, then that will be saved in the database. You can show it using whatever font you like - a nice Indian font, fancy calligraphy font, comic sans, barcode, wingdings - but it is still `tajmhal`.

You need to translate the word or characters from one language to another. That's not a font issue, that requires some mapping from one to the other. The characters will have different unicode values - you can try mapping them yourself, character by character, but this is unlikely to work unless the two languages have the same number of letters and they map directly from one to another. So you need to *translate*.

The other answer suggests using Google. You're writing a desktop application but you can still integrate with Google technology; if network is down then you don't translate and try again later.

Question: if the text is displaying as you want then why do you need to translate it? You're obviously using an english keyboard - why not store the text as english characters?

Comment: she's looking for [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration), not translation.

Comment: @rm. Thank you, you're correct. Transliteration is a type of translation, but not in the common language sense of transferring meanings from one language to another.

Answer (score 2):

Google has a [transliteration api](http://code.google.com/apis/language/transliterate/overview.html) (that is unfortunately deprecated), which might solve your problem. If you need there are other services like [Quillpad](http://www.quillpad.in/gujarati/) that you might want to buy.  These will allow you to type in one script and get the phonetic equivalent in another script - transliteration.  Once you store your data in the database, you should be able to display it again, unless you're storing the English string there by mistake.

Comment: While Google depreciated the 1.0 version, they do plan a 2.0 service, you need to pay a monthly fee to translate up to 1 million character.

Comment: i am creating window based application not web based.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is web-based or a desktop application, you need to interact with a transliteration engine, or build one into your application.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, can you check your datatype in SQL, is it `varchar` or `nvarchar`. `nvarchar` deals with unicode characters.