# unicode for ગુજરાતી letters

Tags: c#, unicode

How can I print Gujarati letters in C#?

I tried:

```
Console.Write('\u0A95');
```

It should print ક,as 0x0A95 is unicode for ક but it displays ? instead.

What's wrong?

Comment: What's "wrong" is your console is not set up to display those characters, or the font being used in the console does not have a glyph for that character.

Comment: Almost a dup... That question is about a textfield, this one is about the console.  Same exact questioner, though. (user:941772)

Comment: Y asking same question for no of time : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396776/language-in-c just edit the question rather than asking new question

Comment: It isn't really duplicate. It's a VERY different problem, the one that Console(s) don't really support Unicode, so please don't close it.

Comment: its solution to my pprevious question.i will try like when the user types into textbox ,i will prevent KeyCode to display.instead recognize latter typed and conver it to relative unicode gujarati latter.hope it work.thank you all for being so fast in helping me.

Answer (score 3):

The Console window has a limited support for Unicode. Many languages can't be rendered correctly because it doesn't have the auto-fallback to another font. To check this, try copy-pasting something in the Command Line. And you can't really change the font of the console. Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/16/2659903.aspx They tried and they saw that it was useless/impossible. Console font must be monospaced and very regular.

And this from probably one of the gurus of Unicode at MS: http://www.siao2.com/2011/08/18/10196878.aspx

> Well, the console can support Unicode, but:
>      - No complex script support
>      - No font substitution
>      - Some console apps don't support Unicode even though the could
>      - 1 and 2 can be fixed by using the PowerShell ISE

Comment: ya i got it.when i tried the same for windowsFormApplication ,it works and displays ક.Thank you a lot for helping and solving so fast.

Comment: @aarti One of the news of .NET 4.5 SHOULD BE a better handling of Unicode in Console (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms171868(VS.110).aspx Console support for Unicode (UTF-16) encoding).